# Autoload composer'a на хостинге

Tags: php, namespace, composer

Доброе время суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - на хостинге не работает autoload composera. А точнее маппинг, который я задал в composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Classes": ""
    }
}
```

В корневой директории есть папка classes,  и там дальше по папкам разложены классы.

Например есть код, который работает у меня на локальном сервере:

```
$catalogClient = Classes\Models\CatalogClient::first('all', array(
     'conditions' => array(
         'userID = ?', $_SESSION['user_id']
     ),
     'order' => 'id desc'
));
```

На локальном сервере композер находит класс по неймспейсу, а на хостинге ошибка

```
Class 'Classes\Models\CatalogClient' not found
```

Есть мысль о том, что `php composer.phar install` нужно сделать и на хостинге, дабы сгенерировать правильный autoload. Но хостер запрещает исполнение phar архивов. Не думаю что в autoloade генерируются и вшиваются полные пути, как на моем локальном (типа C:......). Да и вообще, я не уверен что в этом проблема) А в чем - понять не могу) Есть идейки ? :)

PS. Тэгов "Composer", или "Autoload" к сожалению нет(
PPS. Пробовал даже так

config/environment.php:

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
$loader->add('Classes', __DIR__ . '/../');
```

Ну т.е. в лоадере сказать что ищи директорию Classes в такой то директории.. Но что то всё равно не так :(

Comment: папку vendor скопировал на хостинг?

PS: кстати да, тэг composer вполне уместен! ;)

Comment: Те классы, которые находятся в папке vendor - они загружаются нормально) Я ж говорю - не работает только тот маппинг, который я сам сказал композеру)

Comment: ммм... если на локалке работает, а на серваке нет, то так сходу даже не скажу...

какой-нить автолоадер применяется? может быть он кеширует пути где-то и этот кеш был тоже перенесен на хостинг, а не сгенерирован там?

Comment: Может быть он кеширует пути, да, я об этом написал в вопросе) Проблема в том, что сгенерировать на хостинге нельзя из phar архива) можно конечно исходники композера залить, создать shell скрипт composer.sh, и юзать)) но мне кажется что пока - это не самый лучший и верный путь)

Comment: у меня была похощая проблемма когда я Symfony2 запускал на IIS, он тихо не работал вообще... когда глянул в лог ошибок, действительно он просто не мог загрузить файлы потому что почему-то небыло прав доступа :( приходилось в ИИС выставлять запуск скриптом от моего имени, а не от IUSR, попроуй и у себя права доступа посмореть, может в них дело...

Comment: Тоже думал про права - посмотрел всё, вроде бы правильно там..(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ковыряй Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader смотри по каким путям он чего-то там пытается прочитать и что у тебя в этих путях... кстати вроде есть какая-то настройка пхп opendir или open_basedir они вродебы запрещают доступ к папкам выше указанных, а у тебя вендоры лежат как посмотрю выше... на шаредах такое могут практиковать... вообще конечно если за серьёзные вещи взялся, то переходи на VPS-ки ;) по цене почти тоже самое, а пользы несоизмеримо больше ;)

Comment: Старый проект решил отрефакторить) Есть еще инфа - сейчас отпишу

Comment: перемести vendor в веб папку, чтобы инклюдил $loader = require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

Comment: Не помогло.. Нашел аналогичный трабл: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014561/composer-autoload-not-working-on-production-server

Но пока не совсем понял)

Comment: тогда попробуй ручками написать например 
require '/var/www/xxx/public_html/xxx/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Resources/stubs/SessionHandlerInterface.php' сможет его в принципе подгрузить?

Comment: Да, руками подружает. Вот еще подобное, но тоже не вижу решения: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818690/using-composers-autoload

Comment: тогда залазий в findFile() и натыкивай в него всяких print_r() :) смотри почему он не хочет подгружать ;)

Comment: Решение выше :)

Answer (score 0):

Композер генерирует такой файл:

vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php:

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Symfony\\Component\\Yaml\\' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/yaml/',
    'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/http-foundation/',
    'Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/dependency-injection/',
    'SessionHandlerInterface' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Resources/stubs',
    'Classes' => $baseDir . '/',
);
```

По сути - ничего он не кеширует :)

Обновление:

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
var_dump($loader->findFile('Classes\Models\CatalogClient'));
exit;
```

Локально - находит файл, и возвращает путь до файла.

На хостинге - false

Что ж за черт)

---

Вот сам лоадер, и его пути:

```
object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader)#1 (4) {
  ["prefixes":"Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader":private]=>
  array(5) {
    ["Symfony\Component\Yaml\"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(60) "/var/www/xxx/public_html/xxx.ru/vendor/symfony/yaml/"
    }
    ["Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(71) "/var/www/xxx/public_html/xxx/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/"
    }
    ["Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(76) "/var/www/xxx/public_html/xxx/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/"
    }
    ["SessionHandlerInterface"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(119) "/var/www/xxx/public_html/xxx/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Resources/stubs"
    }
    ["Classes"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(40) "/var/www/xxx/public_html/xxx/"
    }
  }
```

Пути он ставит правильные. Но почему не находит файл, это уже загадка)

---

О боже :) Я совсем забыл, что в unix подобных системах директория classes/ != Classes/. В отличии от виндовоза. Вот оно что :) Переименовав директорию в Classes - я приобрел успех :) Спасибо за отзывчивость :)

Comment: сам композер ничего кешировать небудет... но загрузчик который получен от композера можно во что-нить обернуть, например в https://github.com/symfony/ClassLoader/blob/master/MapClassLoader.php#L26 хотя сам я пользуюсь только ApcClassLoader

Comment: Собсна "xxx" - значит скрыто пользователем :)

Answer (score 0):

В composer.json psr-0, не надо писать заглавными, где то читал что это важно. И у вас все верно.